# Visualize the cosine similarity scores calculated using pretrained word embeddding in SpaCy

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy, word-embedding

I have used SpaCy's pretrained model 'en_core_web_lg' to find the cosine distance between a group of values and attributes. I wanted to visualize the relationship of how close a word is from the other word, very much similar to clustering.

[Here is the link to the table which contains similarity scores for each value vs attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/An012.png)

Here the columns are the attributes for which i am trying to find the similarity score, while the row are the values for which i am trying to find what attribute it is most likely to be classified

[This is the output i am trying to achieve. Please take a look at it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfQLZ.png)

Comment: Have you checked out whatlies? https://spacy.io/universe/project/whatlies

Answer (score 1):

If you want a plot similar to this:
[image: tSNE plot]
you need to **reduce the dimensionality of your word vectors to 2 dimensions**.

So, you have to apply to the desired word vectors a dimensionality reduction algorithm, such as [t-SNE](https://mlexplained.com/2018/09/14/paper-dissected-visualizing-data-using-t-sne-explained/) (which is also implemented in scikit-learn).

Similarity scores are not sufficient to do this; *you need whole vectors*.

[Here](https://www.kaggle.com/jeffd23/visualizing-word-vectors-with-t-sne#Visualizing-Word-Vectors-with-t-SNE), there is a nice Kaggle tutorial about t-SNE for visualizing word vectors. You can customize it, choosing only the words in which you are interested.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering!! I have tried PCA too and i dont know why but reducing dimensionality using PCA worked much better than applying t-SNE dimensionality reduction. Are you knowing why this is happening??

Comment: You can read this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238538/are-there-cases-where-pca-is-more-suitable-than-t-sne
If my answer was useful, please mark it as accepted or score it.